# Where can I get example opengl composite objects?

Tags: c, opengl, graphics

I am trying to build my understanding of OpenGL and see how the 'pros' do things. I am looking for examples of these objects (preferably in `C`) - I've learned through examples so I think it would help others to see it as well :)

I'm very much a nubie at openGL so this may be a stupid question - I'm just looking for objects I can mess around with to get more familiar with openGL. I have found that it's easier for me to pick things up by tweaking an example until it breaks, then fix it :)

@Nicol Bolas - When I say composite objects I mean objects that when linked together create something 'larger.' An example would be a car. It has a body and tires. Maybe I'm not using the correct term here?

Comment: What are "composite objects"? I've been doing stuff with graphics for about 1.5 decades now, and I've never heard that term.

Comment: "Constructive solid geometry", "object hierarchies", "multi-material mesh". Which one?

Comment: Constructive solid geometry looks cool! Wouldn't have thought of it - Looking at the respective wiki pages, I'd say "multi-material mesh" is more what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in this [list of OpenGL based games and applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_OpenGL_programs), particularly the Open Source games.

Also, [Ogre 3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/) is a well-known Open Source graphics engine with an OpenGL renderer.